# MySQL RegEx Search Query

Tags: mysql, regex

I am writing a custom search engine for my website. I am trying to make use of MySQL REGEXP feature. I would like to be able to search for a word separated by spaces to avoid the chances of getting suffixes or prefixes on a word. For example I am trying to search for "appreciate" I want appreciate, not appreciated or unappreciate or unappreciated. Any ideas on how I could do this with MySQL's REGEXP? My idea for this was to look for spaces like maybe so:

```
^appreciate$|^appreciate[:space:]|[:space:]appreciate$|[:space:]appreciate[:space:]
```

I am sure they is a better way of doing it and I have no idea if that even works

Comment: What about if I wanted to add a mutiple words and wanted padding incase somthing appears between them. For example: I want something like "Fish Stick" but want to allow for something such as "I love Fish and a Stick". My idea was: [[:<:]]Fish[[:>:]]?.{1,}[[:<:]]Stick[[:>:]]

Comment: This seems to have worked for me. Well it appears like the more I play with RegEx the easier it becomes to understand and write it. I honestly felt like it was impossible for me to learn it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT 'I appreciate you' REGEXP '[[:<:]]appreciate[[:>:]]'; /* matches */
```

`[[<:]]` and `[[>:]]` are word boundaries. From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html):

> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the alnum class or an underscore (_).

Edit: just to clarify, this also deals with situations where there's a newline character after the word, or a comma, etc

Comment: Works perfect thank you! I didnt read up on but I saw those ones and couldnt understand at the time what 'word boundaries' ment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
^\s*appreciate(\s+.*)*$
```

- Between the start and the word there may be 0+ whitespace parts
- then comes the word
- then if something comes after that, it has to start with whitespace

Comment: MySQL's `REGEXP` function doesn't support \s.

Answer (score 0):

You can seek for non-alphabetic characters:

```
[^[:alpha:]]+
```

... or just word boundaries:

```
[[:<:]]foo[[:>:]]
```

Before making a choice, don't forget to make some tests with commas, dots and non-English chars. Also, take into account that MySQL does not fully support regular expressions in multi-byte strings (such as UTF-8).

Comment: Works perfect thank you! I didnt read up on but I saw those ones and couldnt understand at the time what 'word boundaries' ment. Thanks!